# Does the Egit Eclipse plugin support the use of bugtraq IDs?

Tags: egit

I can't seem to find this in the documentation. I need to be able to set a numerical ID with each commit...

Does anyone know if this is possible?
And if so, how can I enable this in EGit?

Answer (score 0):

References to bug tracking systems are usually put into the commit message.

Some project only include the number, see [the following EGit commit](http://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/commit/?id=c3a6041507f6d32ebef265dca18524d1c2b200ac) for an example. The "Bug: 406542" in the commit message is a reference to Eclipse bug 406542.

Other projects put the full URL to the bug report into the commit message.